# Is there a way to programatically check if @2x images are being used?

Tags: coronasdk

I have a calculation that depends on the frame size in a sprite sheet and this currently breaks when @2x images are used.  So i need to tweak the calculation to adjust for @2x.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the image suffix you are using with:

```
local imageSuffix = display.imageSuffix
print( imageSuffix )
```

Check this [link](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/imageSuffix.html) in Corona docs

Answer (score 0):

Check this [one](http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2012/05/16/pnglib-extract-data-png-files-width-height-color-depth-etc). Do you use any sprite creator in creating your sprites? because basically you can adjust its size prior to creating the sprites. Im using [Texture Packer](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker). It never fails me.